# List all branches from Google Cloud Source Repository

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-source-repositories

I'm a newbie, as i want to fetch/list all the branches created in repository of Google Cloud Source. As AWS has a list-branches functionality but GCP doesn't. Even we have written a function in python but it is returning empty list.

```
def get_branch_list(self, project_name: str):
    branch_list = list()
    branch_list = response["branches"]
    return branch_list
```

As AWS has `self.client_codecommit.list_branches()` function. But GCP is not having such function. Please help guys.

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/source/repos/list) To list all repositories in the current project, run `gcloud source repos list`check if any listed. you can also view in [console](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/browsing-repositories#view_all_repositories)

Comment: Yes i have tried this, as it only list all the repos not the branches.

Comment: Hi @Aakash Bhaikatti I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 1):

Seems, there is no List Branch endpoint available in the Cloud Source Repository API

At [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157267696) a feature request has been submitted for this. which is still open and where further progress can be tracked. There is already a public concern about it, so it is a known problem. You can add your concerns and follow that issue for future updates.

Comment: Aishwarya, thank you for recommending this, hope this will help out.